# AngularJS: validate ng-disabled / ng-readonly fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I scribbled [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/9fdmjg6w/) to describe the problem at hand. Basically I have a form with certain `ng-required` text inputs. The catch is that the user cannot type inside them, but has to click on a button which opens up a dialog with a list of allowed values; clicking on one sets the input's `ng-model` accordingly (in my example, the button next to the input sets the `ng-model` right away, but you get the jist).
Trouble is that if I set `ng-disabled` (comprehensible) or `ng-readonly` (this honestly I can't figure out why) the form is submitted even if the field is left empty, whereas I'd like to enforce user input. How could I achieve this? Cheers.

Comment: you need write your own valid fro this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own validation function on submit:

```
$scope.validateForm = function() {
    if ($scope.myDisabledInput === '') {
        return;
    }
};
```

I would alert the user somehow, but this should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: I guess this is better than nothing, though I was hoping to leverage the `ng-required` attribute

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by adding another input sharing the same model and putting it right below the visible one. You can't just do a hidden input however (either by setting type="hidden" or ng-hide and whatnot), as hiding it entirely won't let the validation show up.

```
<!-- Normal input: we want this to be required, yet read-only -->    
<input id="inputMyValue" ng-model="myValue" ng-click="openSelectionDialog()" ng-readonly="true"/>

<!-- Hidden input: not really hidden - just visible enough for the validation to work -->
<input id="inputMyValueHidden" ng-model="myValue" ng-required="true"  style="height: 0; border: 0;"/>
```